# In Typescript, how can I implementing bare function interface with overloads?

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript 2.3.3

I'm trying to create a nice API for some code I'm writing, so I'm experimenting with what's possible in Typescript's generics.

I'd like to be able to call a function with a generic type, and use that type to present choices to the user, some of which may be functions with different signatures.

Here's my attempt so far.

I declared an interface with two bare function signatures (the two options I'd like to present to the developer):

```
interface api<T1> {

  <T2>(second: T2):  {
    first: T1
    second: T2;
  };

  <T2, T3>(second: T2, third: T3):  {
    first: T1
    second: T2;
    third: T3;
  };

}
```

And I create a function that contains the implementations of each function signature, using the generic type parameter passed to it:

```
const test = <TFirst>(first: TFirst) : api<TFirst> => {

  const impl1 = <T2>(second: T2) => ({
    first, second
  });

  const impl2 = <T2, T3>(second: T2, third: T3) =>({
    first, second, third
  });

  return ...?
};
```

I have no idea, though, where to assign those implementations or how to create a return object that meets api's specification.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. You could do something like this:

```ts
interface api<T1> {

  <T2>(second: T2):  {
    first: T1;
    second: T2;
  };

  <T2, T3>(second: T2, third: T3):  {
    first: T1;
    second: T2;
    third: T3;
  };
};

function createApi<T1>(first: T1): api<T1> {

  function impl<T2>(second: T2): { first: T1; second: T2; };
  function impl<T2, T3>(second: T2, third: T3): { first: T1; second: T2; third: T3; };
  function impl<T2, T3>(second: T2, third?: T3): { first: T1; second: T2; third?: T3; } {
    if (third === undefined) {
      return { first, second };
    }
    return { first, second, third };
  }

  return impl;
}

const test = createApi<number>(1);
console.log(test(2));
console.log(test(2, 3));
```

The `createApi` function just returns an inner, overloaded function.

For more information on TypeScript overloads, see the *Overloads* section in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).